# Regex to match an optional set of either single or groups of characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will match a variety of number forms with or without abbreviations in a variety of languages, and return to me the number (at the beginning of the line) and the rest of the text. For example, if I have:

`12,345 things` should give me `12,345` and `things`

Other forms this might take can include:

`12 things`
`12,345,456 things`

And it can get more complicated, with K/M markers for thousands/millions:

`12.4k things`
`18.4m things`

And with other languages it gets more strange:

`12,4 k things`
`2 345 things`

And sometimes the `k` or `m` might instead be `Tsd.` or `Mio.`, such as:

`12,4 Tsd. things`
`18.3 Mio. things`

In each of these cases, I want a match on the number (if it leads the line) and *with* the units when it was there in the first place (`k` or `Tsd.` for example).

What I have so far is this:

`/^(\d+(?:[,|\s|.]\d+)*\s?[K|k|M|m]?)\s+(.*)/`

This will correctly match all forms *except* for the ones that include `Tsd.` or `Mio.`. But I can't figure out a way to use groups of characters in the alternating character set. How can I add support for `Tsd.` and `Mio.` to this regex?

Comment: Try [`/^(\d[,\s.\d]*(?:[km]|Tsd\.|Mio\.)?)\s+(.*)/i`](https://regex101.com/r/oXDT1m/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another case for your `[K|k|M|m]`-Part:

```
^(\d+(?:[,|\s|.]\d+)*\s?([KkMm]?|Tsd\.|Mio\.))\s+(.*)
```

I added brackets around this and added the two new cases. All your given test cases still worked when testing this with [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xTPop1/1).

Comment: Your `^(\d+(?:[,|\s|.]\d+)*\s?([K|k|M|m|]?|Tsd.|Mio.))\s+(.*)` regex will also match a string like [`12,4| things`](https://regex101.com/r/nebll4/1)

Comment: Yes. I simply used the regex from @mix to make sure that he can see the only difference I added. I included your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a group instead of a set of characters:

```
/^(\d+(?:[,|\s|.]\d+)*\s?(K|k|M|m|Tsd\.|Mio\.)?)\s+things$/
```

The brackets that you use describe a set of characters, to just putting Tsd. in there means T, s, d or . With a group in round parenthesis you get the result you want.

Be careful with the .* at the end because with this you would get a match with the regex you used before on 12,4 Tsd. things and 18.3 Mio. things because the units are optional and .* matches everything including Tsd. and Mio.

Comment: Your `^(\d+(?:[,|\s|.]\d+)*\s?(K|k|M|m|Tsd\.|Mio\.)?)\s+things$` regex will also match a string like [`12|4 things`](https://regex101.com/r/nebll4/2)

Comment: Yes, I know. And a lot of other strings because the first group contains a dot. I was focusing on the question and changed only the relevant part for that.

Comment: A dot in the character class only matches a `.` char.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to use a regex like this:

```
/^((\d[,\s.]?)+(mio\.|tsd\.|k|m)?)\s+(.+)$/gi
```

Side note: Characters inside `[]` will have an *or* operator inside, and you don't need to use `|`.